# How to know if someone is fan of my facebook page?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, fan-page

I know this subject has been done already over and over. but... i must be stupid so i'll try to figure out my problem simply.
I have a facebook page, let s say that one : 
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Medieval-Forgecom/302734029745018
with a few fan poeple.
now on my website i would like to give a discount to poeple who are fan of that page.
So i tried the php api (with an application id and secret) before discovering that this is NOT what i want as my page is not an app and has no appId neither secret. Am i misunderstanding something here?
So i m wondering how in php i can know if someone is fan or not...
If it is not possible i could use the javascript api to make this check ( wich is quite bad, it should be done somewhere via php) but even this way i get trouble with the deprecated api and the code refering to javascript inside the facebook website.
in a nutshell, i'm lost.

thanks  for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do some research on the concept of "fan-gate".  I think this is what you're looking for.

https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150130919053430

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBBnrtG0hAw

Comment: this helps me even if the video is not up to date as the graphic and organisation of the facebook app page change so most of the fields to fill moved...

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways of using Facebook API. **Social plugins** are widgets such as comments or like buttons. You can put them into your site directly and easily. And then there is the **Graph API**. First way of using this API is to create a whole standalone Facebook application, such as Farmwille. Second way is to use it only at your site, out of the Facebook frame. Regardless of the type of your usage, you need to register an **application** on Facebook, so Facebook API can authorize you. Without that you can't use the API. You don't need to create a real standalone app if you want only to use the API at your own site, but you must register it and this registration is just called Facebook application. It can be *virtual* application representing your site.

Comment: i already did this application and linked it to the page i ve shown above, but the like action on the page doesn't seem to be linked to this application. so when i use the php api given by facebok  (linked to the Graph api i guess) it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ah, then sorry, I misunderstood the problem.